# Overload shallow and deep copy constructor cpp

Tags: c++

I am starting with C++ environment, I hope I didn't mess up a lot with the concepts here.

I have one task where I need to create an object that has to be able to be copied in two ways, with a shallow copy and a deep copy.

The object has to allow two types of copies. Either the object is shallow copied or deep copy depending on the demands.

In the code below I create a simple example to explain the use case. There, I implement the object  `Object` with a one-argument constructor and a deep copy constructor. Then at some point we use the functions `get_shallow` and `get_deep`.

Is there a way to tell the compiler which constructor to use when it copies `Object` in the scope of the functions? Sometimes I will need a function to return the shallow copy and other times a deep copy.

```
using namespace std;

class Object;

typedef std::shared_ptr<Object> objectPtr;

class Object{
private:
    int *data;
public:

    Object(int d);
    Object(const Object &source);
    ~Object();
};

// One argument constructor
Object::Object(int d) {
    data = new int;
    *data = d;
}
//deep copy constructor
Object::Object(const Object &source) :Object(*source.data) {}
Object::~Object() {delete data;}

Object get_shallow(Object object) {
    return object;
}
Object get_deep(Object object) {
    return object;
}

int main(){

    Object object1 {100};

    get_deep(object1); //returns a deep copy of the object
    get_shallow(object1); //returns a shallow copy of the object

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The question itself seems to be very misunderstood. You typically need either a shallow copy or a deep copy. If shallow, you don't need to write it yourself. If deep, you will write it yourself, and there will be no shallow copy.

Comment: Any class only has one (and only one) defined copy constructor signature, you can't overwrite it at that level. Rather define dedicated copy functions.

Comment: Why do `get_shallow` and `get_deep` even take arguments? They're member functions so they can only be called when you already have an instance of an `Object`, and presumably you'd just be trying to shallowly or deeply copy that instance. But also this just... Doesn't seem to be a very C++ way of doing things. The C++ idiom would be a reference. ETA: Oh, no, I see the difference between a shallow copy of `obj` and a reference to `obj`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ That could be a solution more reasonable. Could you please elaborate a bit more or show me and example of how to define dedicated copy functions to proceed with the two types of copies of the object (shallow, deep)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a tag on the copy constructor to indicate it is making a shallow copy.

Note carefully that a shallow copy does not own the resources.  So when the owner gets destructed, any shallow copy will have dangling pointers.  That's a very fragile situation, and easily the source of bugs.

An alternative solution is to have a `std::shared_ptr` for the shared resources, and then those resources exist until all owners relinquish ownership (typically relinquishing ownership upon destruction, but could be that they change ownership over the lifecycle of the entity object).

Regardless, here's an example of shallow copy constructor.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::ostream;

class Object {
    int* data;
    bool delete_data = true;
public:
    enum Shallow_tag { shallow };
    ~Object();
    Object(int d);
    Object(Object const&); // DEEP copy.
    Object(Object const&, Shallow_tag); // SHALLOW copy.

    bool is_shallow() const { return !delete_data; }
    auto get_data() const -> int* { return data; }
};

Object::~Object() { if (delete_data) delete data; }

// One argument constructor
Object::Object(int d) : data{new int(d)} { }

//deep copy constructor
Object::Object(Object const& other) : Object(*other.data) {}

// shallow copy
Object::Object(Object const& other, Shallow_tag) : data{other.data}, delete_data{false} {}

Object get_shallow(Object const& object) {
    return Object(object, Object::shallow);
}

Object get_deep(Object object) {
    return object;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Object const& obj) {
    out << (obj.is_shallow() ? "shallow" : "deep") << " ";
    auto d = obj.get_data();
    if (d) out << "data:" << *d;
    else out << "data:(null)";
    return out;
}

int main() {
    auto object1 = Object{100};

    auto obj2 = get_deep(object1); //returns a deep copy of the object
    auto obj3 = get_shallow(object1); //returns a shallow copy of the object

    cout << "obj2 is " << obj2 << "\n";
    cout << "obj3 is " << obj3 << "\n";
}
```

---

UPDATE: using `shared_ptr` for the data.

Of course, an `int` as shared data is probably a bit silly.  But for the purposes of an example it is illustrative of *whatever* the data payload type.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>

using std::cout;
using std::make_shared;
using std::ostream;
using std::shared_ptr;

class Object {
    shared_ptr<int> data;
public:
    Object(int d);

    auto get_data() const -> int* { return data.get(); }
};

Object::Object(int d) : data{make_shared<int>(d)} { }

auto operator<<(ostream& out, Object const& obj) -> ostream& {
    auto d = obj.get_data();
    if (d) out << "data:" << *d;
    else out << "data:(null)";
    return out;
}

Object get_copy(Object o) {
    return o;
}

int main() {
    auto object1 = Object{100};

    auto obj2 = get_copy(object1);
    auto obj3 = get_copy(object1);

    cout << "obj2 is " << obj2 << "\n"; // 100
    cout << "obj3 is " << obj3 << "\n"; // 100

    *object1.get_data() = 5;

    cout << "obj2 is " << obj2 << "\n"; // 5
    cout << "obj3 is " << obj3 << "\n"; // 5

    obj2 = Object{75};

    cout << "obj2 is " << obj2 << "\n"; // 75
    cout << "obj3 is " << obj3 << "\n"; // 5
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this explanation is very helpful, I think I can work with that. Although, I am wondering now, how the alternative with the `std::shared_ptr` could look like.

Comment: Maybe the real question is how to nicely provide a deep-copy function for a type that *does* use `std::shared_ptr` so that both kinds of copies are meaningful.

Comment: @DavisHerring • That's why I have the `obj2 = Object{75};` example of doing a deep copy replacement.

Comment: @Eljay: Sure, but it looks very different if the copy has to be implemented by the class because the types are more complicated and/or don’t match the ordinary constructor interface.